# EGL not swapping on Raspberry VideoCore IV

Tags: c#, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, egl, broadcom

I'm trying to run my OpenGL wrapper on Raspberry Pi 2. The wrapper is running on mono, written in C#. I got my basic example running on RPi using VideoCore IV API, but no image is presented on the screen.

The example located in `/opt/vc/src/hello_triangle` is working flawlessly, and my program doesn't catch any error. It seems that `eglSwapBuffers` simply don't swap anything.

You can find the BCM/EGL/GL call log of my application on this [issue](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/issues/24). You can get the entire source of the sample [here](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net).

Comment: I believe that on VideoCore, OpenGL output goes into a separate framebuffer that is not displayed by default.  You have to use the platform layer-management API to enable it, should be some files in `/sys` for that purpose.

Comment: If it is, I don't understand why C sample is working.

Comment: The [hello_triangle sample](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangle/triangle.c) contains [calls](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangle/triangle.c#L161) to a bunch of `vc_dispmanx_`\* functions, does your code do that?

Comment: yes, they are listed in the link.

Comment: Where in your code is the call to `eglCreateWindowSurface`?  It's not helpful to dump a link to a repo of a few thousand files, how can anyone besides the author hope to find anything?

Comment: Seems the call is [here](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/blob/master/OpenGL.Net/DeviceContextEGL.cs#L322), how does `_WindowHandle` get pointed to `_NativeWindow` in your `VideoCoreWindow` instance?

Comment: The call log is listed [here](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/issues/24). The repository is useful for getting the entire source code, but the actual call sequence in in the issue page. The *_WindowHandle* is the pinned address of the structure allocated [here](https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/blob/master/OpenGL.Net.VideoCore/VideoCoreWindow.cs#L59).

Comment: ...and in the meanwhile I forgot to push the last edits. Now everything should be aligned to my current working directory.

Comment: I swear this line `public IntPtr Handle { get { return (_NativeWindowLock.Address); } }` was a hard-coded `IntPtr.Zero` when you asked this question....

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right: that's why I commented about. I forgot to push my commits before posting this question on SO. Sorry for that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem is in

```
glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

... Did you notice the zero on alpha? Yes. VideoCore IV, having a 32 bit framebuffer, blends the window content with the background color.

That's it.